# Type BuildConfig is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle

I'm working on a multi module Android application and everything was working in a debug mode but now when I try to build a release package I'm receiving this error:

```
Type ***module1.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:
***/module1/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes/release/classes.jar:***/module1/BuildConfig.class,
***/module2/build/intermediates/runtime_library_classes/release/classes.jar:***/module1/BuildConfig.class
```

It's the first time I'm seeing an error like this and I don't know how to fix this and what's even causing it. As far as I'm aware library modules shouldn't even be generating BuildConfig files in release mode.

Comment: check if both modules has same package name

Comment: Please post your Gradle file

Comment: Well now I feel stupid. I had the same packages defined in both manifests.

Comment: No worries. It happens :D

Comment: I had the same packages defined in both build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 166, accepted):

> check if both modules have a same package name

Comment: i have this issue in my case : 
Type com.BV.LinearGradient.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex, /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out/classes.dex

i don't know what's the solution

Comment: Build -> Rebuild Project might help

Comment: @Yacine i m also facing same issue . have you found any solution ?

Comment: i had to change the name of modules in node_modules

Comment: Check the package name in the AndroidManifest also!

Comment: I had an issue where I've defined same package name in module manifest file. Updating it with adding module name suffix solved  the issue

Comment: Thanks, I had two samples in my library with the same package name and renaming the samples with different package names from the library fixed the issue for me.

Comment: My solution: I renamed one of two file paths:sample.jar file's name in the directory manually. Then, I tried to generate the signed app because sometimes make-project may be unhealty for kinda build, so, it is working safely now!

Answer (score 26):

My Android Manifest Had the same Package Name for two Diferent Modules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.repeated.package">
```

Answer (score 17):

Most probably both shared AndroidManifest.xml and androidApp AndroidManifest.xml has the same packageId. They have to be different. For example, com.my.app.shared and com.my.app.android

Answer (score 10):

I'm using Android Studio 4.0.1 on MacOS

On my network drive within the project `app` folder, I searched for `BuildConfig`

I noticed a `BuildConfig 2.class` file had been generated.

I deleted the `BuildConfig 2.class` file, rebuilt, re-ran and everything was fine.

UPDATE

I ran into a situation where a `BuildConfig 3.class` showed up, so now I search by `Config`  (Config+space)

UPDATE 2

I have this issue continuously every time I run.  Now rather than deleting the file, I use, menu item

```
"Build"->"Clean Project"
```

Then re-run the app.

Comment: Thank you, just cleaning the project was enough.

Answer (score 7):

In my case,
I have a multi-module project, also got the same issue.
I checked every manifest and package name, which contain duplicates of another.
I found the duplicate and renamed a package and manifest package name and did a Build -> Clean Project now the issue is resolved!

- Check Duplicate Package, Manifest entry
- Try Invalidate cache, Clean Build, Rebuild a Project
- Try to delete .gradle directory and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 6):

For me adding the following line to `android/app/build.gradle` into the following section helped:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
        ...
        exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-linear-gradient' // <<<---- this line was added
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Rebuilding the app fixed the issue for me.

If rebuilding is not fixing the issue Check this out : https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes

Answer (score 2):

I get the error after upgrading the firebase project level dependency on the android project

```
classpath 'com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4'
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

to solve my error I am updated the above to

```
classpath ('com.google.firebase:perf-plugin:1.3.4') {
     exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
 }
classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.4.1'
```

and go to the project folder and  delete build/intermediates

1. app/build/intermediates  delete this folder
2. invalidate the cache and restart
3. after. restart - rebuild and run

Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was sharing a `build.gradle` file with a namespace declared in multiple modules. Removing the namespace declaration made it work again

Answer (score 1):

The only solution that worked for me was to delete the ~/.gradle folder in my home folder (mac osx).

Edit: After a while it happened again - so I deleted the whole project and cloned it again from github. That fixed it completely without happen ever again.

Answer (score 1):

> Type com.e.pacakgename.MainActivity is defined multiple times.

I also faced this error, and in my case there was 2 MainActivity files in my project.

After removing one file the error is solved.

Answer (score 1):

if you have a multi-module project check build.gradle.kts file and If they both have same name space change one so that they do not match.
Clean project then rebuild. (NB: This is Android related).

Answer (score 1):

This is how this happened to me when using React Native:

Following different tutorials, my `package.json` file contained these two packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.3.1",
    ...
  }
```

One was added automatically, another one added manually, following a tutorial. The solution is to remove the "community"-marked package.

The solution is specific for React Native, but the takeaway could be, check mutually exclusive dependencies like this.

Comment: thanks, somehow I had this exact same situation. I don't even know how it got there!

Answer (score 0):

For those searching like me :(, This worked. I had JitsiMeet and that is the reason, this happens. I found in Jitsimeet repo.

on app/build.gradle:

```
implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.react',module:'react-native-google-signin'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The only solution that worked for me was to delete the ~/.gradle folder in my home folder (mac osx).

At first, I believed that this solution might resolve the issue. However, then, I discovered that I unintentionally added the same dependency twice in my build.gradle file, originating from two distinct repositories. After removing the redundant entry, I successfully resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

While creating new module with app's package name,
namespace in build.gradle file of new module generates with app's package name,
rename it or remove that namespace line based on requirement, and compile, would work.

Example

change

`namespace 'com.cool.dude'`

to

`namespace 'com.cool.dude.libName'`

Answer (score -1):

```
 buildTypes {
    debug {
        buildConfigField "String", "BaseApi", "\"https://{apiUrlDebug}\""

    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "String", "BaseApi", "\"https://{apiUrlRelease}\""
 
        zipAlignEnabled true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        pseudoLocalesEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        lintOptions {

            checkReleaseBuilds false
            abortOnError false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Click on Build->Clean Project