# Type sdk.chat.core.BuildConfig is defined multiple times

Tags: android, gradle

This is the problem I am facing right now. When I build on debug mode it works fine now I am trying to release the apk file it shows. I am using multiple module. And manifest file is ok.
What should I do to fix this problem?

error:

```
Type sdk.chat.core.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: F:\works\New Folder\Ramfolinee\chat-sdk-core\build\.transforms\01ae4b258926b7a18889d4cd8c45b46a\classes\classes.dex, F:\works\New Folder\Ramfolinee\app\build\intermediates\external_libs_dex\developmentRelease\out\classes5.dex
```

[image: This is the error what I recieve]

Comment: [Check the modules have same package name or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507686/type-buildconfig-is-defined-multiple-times)