# android release proguard minify option

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

I'm building the library as a release, creating a "aar" file, and injecting dependencies into my project.

There is no problem with debug, but the following error occurs when it is released.

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type o.a is defined multiple times:~~~~}

This is My Library Build Type

```
release {
        minifyEnabled true
        debuggable false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }

    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
        debuggable true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
```

Android Gradle PluginVersion : 7.3.0

Gradle Version : 7.5

targetSdkVersion 32

compileSdkVersion 33

buildToolsVersion '32.0.0'

What's the problem?

Comment: Check this : [Type BuildConfig is defined multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507686/type-buildconfig-is-defined-multiple-times)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I checked, but there was no duplicate package or class name crying

Redundant paths
\app\build\intermediates\javac\release\classes\o\a.class
It's coming out like this. What's the problem?

Comment: The package name for the library is
It's "com.example.library"

The package name of the app is
"com.example.appname"

Comment: Is there any error when you build aar for debug version?

Comment: Yes... Debug is not happen error