# A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate

Tags: flutter, react-native, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am getting this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
   > There was a failure while executing work items
      > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
         > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives: 
           Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
           Type com.goodnewshub.app.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/kavyabhargava/FlutterDev/goodnews_app/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/debug/out/com/goodnewshub/app/BuildConfig.dex, /Users/kavyabhargava/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/cached_video_player-2.0.4/android/build/.transforms/633574647222525a434eb21c493916d5/transformed/classes/classes.dex

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 12s
[!] App requires Multidex support
    Multidex support is required for your android app to build since the number of methods has exceeded 64k. See https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#enabling-multidex-support for more information. You may pass the --no-multidex flag to skip Flutter's multidex support to use a manual solution.
    Flutter tool can add multidex support. The following file will be added by flutter:
        android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/app/FlutterMultiDexApplication.java
cannot prompt without a terminal ui
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I have already added this to my app/build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
        
        multiDexEnabled true
        
    }
dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

not sure why I am still receiving the error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507686/type-buildconfig-is-defined-multiple-times

Comment: yeah, good point from @HardikMehta, you most probably just need to clean, rebuild, and maybe check if you have duplicates in your packages list, and check out the post mentioned above